# How can I open a specific frame, using cURL, while also giving a parameter

Tags: php, html, curl

I'm currently making a site with three frames. Two columns, with the second having two rows.

Frame 1 shows a list of countries from a database, in the form of URLs which open in Frame 3 along with the country's id, so that only regions in that country are selected.

Now what I'm trying to do is have the header also get the country's id, so that I can have it say 'Welcome to $country'. I tried using cURL to open the header, but couldn't figure out how to do this.

My current PHP to retrieve the id(which works) and open the frame(which doesn't work) looks like this:

```
if(isset($_GET['land']) ){
    $country_id = $_GET['land'];
    }
    else {                      
    $country_id = "1";
    }

$ch = curl_init('header.php?land='.$country_id.'target=\'header\'');
curl_exec($ch);
```

Meanwhile, my header's code looks like following

```
if(isset($_GET['land']) ){
    $country_id = $_GET['land'];
    }
    else {                      
        $country_id = "1";
    }

echo $country_id;
```

I searched Google, SO and some other sites, but couldn't figure out how to do it. Thanks for either the time to read or respond.

Comment: Frames are a web technology from the 80th. You sure you want to use such old stuff? You can, but frames open a whole pothole of problems...

Comment: @arkascha Is there an alternative? I really don't know.

Comment: Well, these days one can use client side scripting (ECMA/javascript) for dynamic layout and content manipulation. This gives you much more freedom and you do not get these hard boundaries where your logic is separated.

Comment: The contemporary method of handling multi-source requests and updating content dynamically, is to use AJAX techniques along with a resource like jQuery. Basically you use JavaScript to do requests and handle the data returned, updating parts of the page dynamically.

Comment: @arkascha I just tried getting the result I wanted with Javascript and am glad to say it was a success!

Is there a way to mark a question as answered-ish without an answer or should I just leave it as it is?

Comment: I copied my comments as an answer, so you have something to accept ;-)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Frames are a web technology from the 80th. You sure you want to use such old stuff? You can, but frames open a whole pothole of problems...

These days one can use client side scripting (ECMA/javascript) for dynamic layout and content manipulation. This gives you much more freedom and you do not get these hard boundaries where your logic is separated.